# React: Why is my state component not rendering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using context and reducer API for state management and logic.
The below code returns context provider, which is called in App.js.
Why isn't the component rendering?

SingerState.js

```
import React, { useReducer } from "react";

import SingerContext from "./singerContext";
import SingerReducer from "./singerReducer";

import { GET_SINGER, SET_LOADING } from "../types";

const SingerState = (props) => {
  console.log('foo')
  const initialState = {
    name: null,
    songs: null,
    loading: false,
  };
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(SingerReducer, initialState);

  const getSinger = () => {
    dispatch({
      type: GET_SINGER,
      payload: {
        name: "jb",
        songs: ["song1", "song2"],
      },
    });
  };
  const setLoading = () => {
    dispatch({
      type: SET_LOADING,
    });
  };
  return (
    <SingerContext.Provider
      value={{
        name: state.name,
        songs: state.songs,
        loading: state.loading,
        getSinger,
        setLoading,
      }}
    >
      {props.childer}
    </SingerContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default SingerState;
```

The entire code is in here: https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-shockley-9u2xb?file=/src/App.js:0-411

App.js

```
import "./App.css";
// import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import SingerState from "./context/singer/singerState";

import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import Singer from "./components/singer/Singer";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <Navbar />
      <SingerState>
        <Singer />
      </SingerState>
    </div>
  );
}
```

singerReducer.js

```
import { GET_SINGER, SET_LOADING } from "../types";

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.types) {
    case GET_SINGER:
      return {
        ...state,
        name: action.payload.name,
        song: action.payload.song,
        loading: false,
      };
    case SET_LOADING:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
export default reducer;
```

singerContext.js

```
import { createContext } from "react";
const singerContext = createContext();
export default singerContext;
```

Comment: In the future be careful with your typos

Answer (score 2):

It should be `{props.children}` not `{props.childer}` in **SingerState.js**. I made this correction inside your **Sandbox** and it is working. To make sure, I changed `initialState` to this :

```js
const initialState = {
  name: "It's me",
  songs: null,
  loading: false,
};
```

Comment: Thanks! It is working now. I was wondering why I wasn't getting a console error here. Could you point out why?

Comment: Glad it worked out ! You are not getting a console error because it is actually not an error. `props.childer` will just return undefined. That's how JavaScript works, when you access a propriety (that doesn't exist) of an object, it just return undefined.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2  typos  in your code:
1-
It should be {props.children} not {props.childer} in SingerState.js. (Thanks to Youssouf Oumar)

And in SingerReducer.js.
Instead of :

```js
switch (action.types) {
    case GET_SINGER:
```

use `action.type` because `types` is not defined

Be carefully with typos!!!